# scilab, how do I search for strings in matrix with exact match

Tags: string, search, scilab

how do I find an exact match of a string in a matrix with scilab. 
"grep" does not give exact match. 
e.g. when I search for "H2" it also shows "H2O"
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you use regular expressions which contain also string start `^` and string end `$` marks?

Comment: well, thank you for your hint! 10 minutes regular expressions tutorial solved this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -w "H2" <file name>`

See following links for more information:

- [www.gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Matching-Control)
- [www.computerhope.com](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugrep.htm)
- [www.thegeekstuff.com](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/15-practical-unix-grep-command-examples/)